# Locate image on screen using pyautogui down to up

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

Basically I have a mini code that detects a copy image on screen. However there are multiple images of the copy image on screen and I want it to detect the one starting from the bottom of the screen to up rather than what is is in default up to down

Didn't try anything, just searched but couldn't find anything. Help appreciated.